# Stringify template type for inline assembler

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inline-assembly

I am looking for a way to automate gcc inline assembly calls through template functions.
For example I have the following dummy function to store a value into a pointer. For now I specialize the template function for different types. Every time something changes in the code, I need to change it for every specialization.

```
template <typename T>
void store_ptr(T *location, T value);

template <>
void store_ptr<char>(char *location, char value) {
  __asm__ __volatile__(
      "strb %1, [%0]\n\t"
      : "+r" (location)
      : "r" (value)
      : "memory"
  );
}


template <>
void store_ptr<short>(short *location, short value) {
  __asm__ __volatile__(
      "strh %1, [%0]\n\t"
      : "+r" (location)
      : "r" (value)
      : "memory"
  );
}
```

It would be nice if the template could stringify the instruction appendix ("b", "h" ...) depending on the template type.

```
template <typename T>
void store_ptr<T>(T *location, T value) {
  __asm__ __volatile__(
     "str" stringify_template_type(T) " %1, [%0]\n\t"
     : "+r" (location)
     : "r" (value)
     : "memory"
     );
}
```

Is there a (simple) way of achieving this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35955645/1460794

Comment: @rex unfortunately, that's not what I am looking for, because in that answer, they are using  a template value in their assembly. I need the template type to be integrated into the assembly instruction

Comment: @MikevanDyke for that you'd need to reflect the name of the template type. I suggest you to look [ctti](https://github.com/Manu343726/ctti). They found a way to extract the template type name from function signature macros.

Comment: Is `str` the x86 Store Task Register instruction?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin No, its the arm-v7 store instruction

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot hmm, this was a good hint, but it seems, that it is not possible to achieve what I want to do, because the inline assembler only takes preprocessor macros and the templates will be compiled after the preprocessor has done the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with the preprocessor and `sizeof`; the template string has to be an actual string literal, not a constant-expression involving `sizeof` and ternaries or anything like that.  And `sizeof(foo)` isn't available as an integer to the preprocessor for its conditionals, even without templates.

I don't know how to do this for ARM, but I think the only plausible way is to use special stuff inside the template string that GCC knows how to expand to to a suffix.  x86's `%z0` doesn't work for ARM, I tried.  But I didn't check the GCC source code for the list of modifiers.

---

For x86 AT&T syntax, this is possible with the `z` [modifier](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86-Operand-Modifiers) to print the operand-size suffix corresponding to the type of the operand.  e.g. `%z0` is `b` if the first operand is a `char`.  While regular `%0` might expand to `%al`, a byte register.

You'd use it like this:

```
template <typename T>
void store_ptr<T>(T *location, T value) {
  __asm__ __volatile__(
     "mov%z0   %1, %0"
     : "=m" (*location)  // let the compiler pick an addressing mode
     : "re" (value)      // register or up-to-imm32 source
     :  // "memory"  // the compiler knows that *location is the only memory written
     );
}
```

e.g.

```
void test(void *dst, int x) {
   store_ptr((int*)dst, x);
   store_ptr((short*)dst, short(x));
   store_ptr((char*)dst, char(-123));
   store_ptr((long*)dst, long(-123));
   store_ptr((long*)dst, long(0x00000000ffffffff));  // doesn't fit in sign-extended imm32
   store_ptr((unsigned*)dst, unsigned(0xffffffff));  // does fit, uses an immediate
   store_ptr((short*)dst, short(123));
}
```

This compiles correctly on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:20,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:20,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:11),source:%27template+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Avoid+store_ptr(T+*location,+T+value)+%7B%0A++__asm__+__volatile__(%0A+++++%22mov%25z0+++%251,+%250%22%0A+++++:+%22%3Dm%22+(*location)++//+let+the+compiler+pick+an+addressing+mode%0A+++++:+%22re%22+(value)++++++//+register+or+up-to-imm32+source%0A+++++:++//+%22memory%22++//+the+compiler+knows+that+*location+is+the+only+memory+written%0A+++++)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+test(void+*dst,+int+x)+%7B%0A+++store_ptr((int*)dst,+x)%3B%0A+++store_ptr((short*)dst,+short(x))%3B%0A+++store_ptr((char*)dst,+char(-123))%3B%0A+++store_ptr((long*)dst,+long(-123))%3B%0A+++store_ptr((long*)dst,+long(0x00000000ffffffff))%3B++//+doesn!%27t+fit+in+sign-extended+imm32%0A+++store_ptr((unsigned*)dst,+unsigned(0xffffffff))%3B++//+does+fit,+uses+an+immediate%0A+++store_ptr((short*)dst,+short(123))%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%232%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:48.98488120950324,l:%274%27,m:63.41212744090442,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1701,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:90,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:90,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:90,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:90,startLineNumber:4),source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:36.58787255909558,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:48.98488120950324,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.07525260577401,l:%274%27,m:35.49095607235142,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27ARM+GCC+13.2.0%27,editorid:2,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:29.018087855297154,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+17.0.1%27,editorid:2,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),l:%274%27,m:35.49095607235142,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:51.01511879049676,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), with x86-64 GCC for AT&T syntax.  (But not Clang 17; it doesn't seem to understand the `%z0` modifier.)   I checked the "link to binary" or "compile to binary object" to verify that this compiler-generated asm also assembles; GCC doesn't verify that, it just does string substitution into the assembler template, like a printf format string.

```
test(void*, int):               # pointer in RDI, int in ESI
        movl   %esi, (%rdi)     # AT&T is   op  src, dst    opposite of ARM insn other than str
        movw   %si, (%rdi)
        movb   $-123, (%rdi)
        movq   $-123, (%rdi)         # mov $sign_extended_imm32, m64

        movl    $4294967295, %eax    # put 0x00000000ffffffff into RAX via mov $-1, %eax
        movq   %rax, (%rdi)          # this is the actual inline asm template, the previous instruction was generated to set up the "r" operand

        movl   $-1, (%rdi)          # unsigned(0xffffffff) does match an "e" constraint
        movw   $123, (%rdi)
        ret
```

I could have done stuff like `(long*)dst+x` or `dst+8` to get other addressing modes as well, e.g. `(%rdi,%rsi,8)` after sign-extending ESI to RSI.

Comment: (The operand-size suffix is optional in AT&T syntax when a register operand like `%si` implies a size.  I used immediate operands to demo a case where the suffix was required.  `mov $1, (%rdi)` is ambiguous and GAS rejects it with an error.  Fun fact: `add $1, (%rdi)` is also ambiguous, but GAS unfortunately defaults to dword operand-size for mnemonics other than `mov`, with recent versions warning, before that silently accepting ambiguous instructions.

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in the comments, this is not possible as the inline assembler only takes preprocessor macros which will be evaluated before the templates.